# Updating text area dynamically when image is deleted in jquery/js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [Gridster](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/) widget for webpage.I have widgets which have images on them.JSON gives data about what image should be there on each grid(I get text from JSON and then get corresponding image from database).
I have textarea field on my widgets which extracts the value of "html" field from the JSON.This value is corresoponding to image present on the widget.
I have a button on each image which deletes the image.I want to delete the content of textarea when I remove the image dynamically.So that when I use [Serialize](http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/#serialize_method). again there should be updated values in JSON

My JS:

```
var gridster;


gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster({
  widget_base_dimensions: [100, 100],
  widget_margins: [5, 5],
  helper: 'clone',
  serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {return {images: $w.find('textarea').val().trim() , col: wgd.col, row: wgd.row, size_x: wgd.size_x, size_y: wgd.size_y}}, 
  resize: {
    enabled: true
  }
}).data('gridster');


//Function for deleting images

$('.removediv').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('div.imagewrap').remove();
  //something that will update textarea by removing the deleted image
  //address.

});
```

HTML:

```
<button class="js-seralize btn btn-success mr-2">Serialize</button>
<textarea id="log"></textarea>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04gdwjj4/) will explain it in a good way

Comment: Does that not work `getElementById('log').value = '';`?

Comment: <textarea> with id log is the final result which will be generated after I click serialize

Comment: For each widget there is a <textarea> defined in the loop which runs over json

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/04gdwjj4/3/

Comment: But there is a case that there can be multiple images in JSON.So is there anyway I can remove content only to the image which is deleted

Comment: The fiddle seems perfect But just a quick question Is it clearing the entire text area or just the name of the image which is deleted

Comment: @Rookie_123 the entire textarea element is being cleared with `.val("")` - its value becomes an empty string.

Comment: I dont want that.I just want to clear the image address which is deleted

Comment: For example you can type in the textarea seperated by comma to the image path.So i would like to retain that text.Just the image which is deleted should go from textarea

Comment: See this fiddle it will give you what I am saying https://jsfiddle.net/mq92g3hb/

Comment: There in the first grid I have added some text after the link.When I click the cross below that widget I want just image link to go and not the entire textarea content

Comment: You have to copy the code into the question in a working sample (should be straight forward using the code snippet feature) as keeping up with fiddles will be hard. Also, it looks like your `src` contains the complete text `<img src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/2258/addictive_flavour/48/game_controller.png,abc,def" class="image">` if you have a single image with all the text it's hard to separate them out. If you have multiple images then it's easier.

Comment: @Rookie_123 Ok, I think I know what you mean now - https://jsfiddle.net/04gdwjj4/13/

Comment: @user7290573 That is not deleting the image

Comment: @Rookie_123 sorry - wrong link; updated!

Comment: @Nope I am struck with also loading the multiple images on widget so I cannot entirely represent how the actual code in the json loop will look like.But my textarea has to be of the way I mentioned.(Image links seperated by commas)So I manually put it for now

Comment: @user7290573 So now the code will look for different img src and then clear that particular src which for which the image is deleted ?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Rookie_123 It will find and remove any instance of the image's `src` attribute within the textarea element.

Comment: So with multiple img src this should work fine

Comment: Add this as an answer in that case so I can accept the answer

Comment: and thanks for your help :)